# Using Bootstrap Clockpicker in modal dialog

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [this](http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) clockpicker plugin for Bootstrap in my project. Everything works fine when used on a normal page. But when used in a modal dialog, the values are not being picked by the plugin. I am able to select the hours and minutes, but the clock simply disappears once I click on AM/PM or Done button. 
Also when the modal is scrolled, the clockpicker stays fixed in its initial position, but that's not the case in a normal page. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the issue with modal box. Actually, initially modal is not visible and you would have called the clockpicker before modal box is shown.
Try, opening modal box first and then clockpicker js.you can try opening modal box through js.

```
$(selector).click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');  // #myModal (id of modal box)
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();   // clockpicker js
        });
```

If still it's not working then try adding some minor delay to clockpicker js
For EG:

```
 $(selector).click(function () {
       function show_popup() {
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();   // clockpicker js  
        };
        window.setTimeout(show_popup, 1000); // 1 seconds    
 });
```

Comment: I am calling modal through data attribute and initializing the clock picker in jquery. The clock picker shows up properly, only problem is it is not picking up the values

Comment: In that case you have to look into your plugin or jquery you have declared for colorpicker

Comment: Setting autoclose:false worked. However I cannot use the 12 hour format now, the selection of AM or PM is being ignored and the value is always set to PM. Tried this(https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/issues/26 ) suggested link as well. But no one seems to have a solution

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a few months late, but I found a potential fix.  Changing the am/pm buttons to divs instead of buttons fixes the issue, at least for me.  I grabbed an updated version of the code by JordyMoos [here](https://github.com/JordyMoos/clockpicker).  This was tested only in a bootstrap modal using autoclose:true and twelvehour:true.

Under if(options.twelvehour) change the following two lines as shown:

```
$('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button am-button">' + "AM" + '</button>')
```

Becomes

```
$('<div class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button am-button">' + "AM" + '</div>')
```

and

```
$('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button pm-button">' + "PM" + '</button>')
```

becomes

```
$('<div class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button pm-button">' + "PM" + '</div>')
```

This issue is caused by the click target being detected as .modal.fade.in instead of the button (the button is detected immediately after, but this isn't helpful since the clock is already hidden).

Comment: Thank you sir, your fix seems to be working, Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the only solution I've found that works

Comment: Great Solution. it is also work for `$('#clock').clockpicker({
    autoclose: false
});`

Comment: change one more text: `('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block clockpicker-button">'+r.donetext+"</button >")` to `('<div class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block clockpicker-button">'+r.donetext+"</div>")`

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a related open issue on github project:

https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/issues/26

Could you try to initialize the plugin with autoclose property with true value?

```
$('#clock').clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: this fix only works if `twelvehour: false`, do you have any idea how to fix for `twelvehour: true`? it all sets the time to `PM`

Answer (score 2):

I published a fix for this issue and added several more options involving twelve hour time here: https://github.com/diracleo/bootstrap-clockpicker

Comment: AMAZING WORK -- Yep, this totally fixes the OP's issue. I can now select AM/PM in the Modal popup. You rock.